# Getting ReplyRequiredException in Spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying out spring cloud dataflow. I created a stream with 'source' as "maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:file-source-kafka:1.0.2.RELEASE", I have written my custom processor and the 'sink' is "maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:log-sink-kafka:1.0.2.RELEASE". The source read a file from a particular directory and pass the reference of the file to the processor. But I see following exception in the processor. The properties for processor looks like below

```
spring.application.name=data-processor
spring.cloud.stream.defaultBinder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zookeeper
spring.cloud..stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka
spring.cloud..stream.bindings.input.destination=dataProcessor
spring.cloud..stream.bindings.output.destination=log
```

---

```
Error while processing: KafkaMessage [Message(magic = 0, attributes = 0, crc = 4142235045, key = null, payload = java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=116 cap=116]), KafkaMessageMetadata [offset=1, nextOffset=2, Partition[topic='Stream.file', id=0]]

org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'dataImporterProcessor.process.transformer.handler', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: You need to show your custom processor `No reply produced by handler 'dataImporterProcessor.process.transformer.handler', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true. at ` means you have a transformer that's returning no result, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell

Comment: When I am trying to return it having problem. So in the script block I have put return 'Hello' and it still say error.